# SQLConnection transaction field value turns to nothing (null) when another asmx service method is called

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have some fields inside an asmx web service. They look like this:

```
Private sqlDbConn As SqlConnection
Private sqlCmd As SqlCommand
Private dbConnStr As String = getDbConnStr(10)
Private trans As SqlTransaction
```

I have a method that defines the values of those fields. It looks like this:

```
 sqlDbConn = New SqlConnection(dbConnStr)
 sqlCmd = New SqlCommand
 sqlCmd.Connection = sqlDbConn

 sqlDbConn.Open()

 trans = sqlDbConn.BeginTransaction()
```

But then, when I call another method inside the same asmx from within the method that defines the values of those fields, every field stays with it's value, except trans. Trans value turns to nothing, it turns to null. I need this transaction in order to pass it to the adapter of the other method, because all the calls to the database between these two methods needs to be in the same transaction.

What's wrong? Why my trans variable turns to nothing (null)??

Comment: Those are fields, not properties.

Comment: There's no reason that a field should spontaneously become `null` and you say that it happens when some code that you haven't shown us is executed, so that makes it all but impossible for us to help you.  All I can recommend is that you debug properly, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through the code, watching the state at each step, then report ALL the relevant information here if you still can't figure out the issue.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you don't have a local variable with the same name somewhere?

Comment: @jmcilhinney you are right. I use the terms interchangeably but you are right.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I debugged line by line, I put a watch on the variable, and it turns to nothing immediately when entering to the next method. I don't think there's other variable with the same name, but I'll double check.

Comment: Perhaps you should make that `trans` field at least a property for the time being.  That way, you can implement a setter and put a breakpoint on it.  That will allow you to see when it's set and where the assignment cam from.  That's a good example of why you shouldn't use the terms interchangeably in a context where they both have a specific meaning.

Comment: Does "when I call another method" mean next request? In that case the the trans field is not preserved. Look at [TransactionScope Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope) it is by my opinion much more usable than SqlTransaction.

Comment: @IvanH is not a next request. I call the other method, inside the same asmx. The other variables stays with their valuable, but "trans" do not.